# Jquery Unobtrusive Validation: add class to label of invalid field

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I'm using jQuery Unobtrusive Validation in an ASP.NET MVC project and validation attributes on properties in a ViewModel.

I have the following code from my form in a partial view:

```
<div id="contact-form">
  <p>
    <label for="Name">Name</label>
    <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"><span for="Name" generated="true" class="">field is required</span></span> <br>
    <input class="input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-required="field is required" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" value="">
  </p>
</div>
```

[image]

**Q:** How can I add a class to the labels of the invalid fields so that when the validation message appears next to the labels, the labels should be red also, using jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You could handle the blur event and check if the value is valid

```
$('input[type=text], textarea').blur(function () {
  if (!$(this).valid()) {
    $(this).prevAll('label').css('color', 'red');
  }
});
```

In case controls are skipped, you might also need to check the submit event and repeat the same for each input, textarea etc.